# private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) parameter token is never used

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have tried every answer available but to no avail. What am I missing here?

```
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token)`{
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I have tried every method available but still my fcm token does not register in logcat. The parameter token is never used. I have even put a button on my main activity as in the quickstart example that I keep getting diverted to.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments section, the question is vague, but I kinda get what you're asking.

The `sendRegistrationToServer()` is an optional method that can be seen in most of the examples from Firebase. From [GitHub example](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/93c33ac9eeb76d6f7bd6c6d39d8a252de15c6b13/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java):

```
package com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;


public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
    }
}
```

From here, you can see that the `sendRegistrationToServer()` is called inside `onTokenRefresh()`, where the registration token used for FCM is generated. The code documentation already tells what is supposed to happen inside `sendRegistrationToServer()`:

> Persist token to third-party servers. Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account maintained by your application.

Sending the registration token towards your own App Server is optional, but it is strongly advised to do so (see [FCM docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#monitor-token-generation)). So that you may have the token for future use.

Comment: cannot resolve mthode `getApplication` error. Can you help me with this error: `private void sendRegistrationToServer(@Nullable String token) {
        if (token != null) {
            ((SubApp) getApplication()).getRepository().registerInstanceId(token);
            // No need to unregister the previous Instance ID token because the server
            // automatically removes invalidated tokens.
        }
    }`

Comment: @NamikazeMinato `sendRegistrationToServer` is a custom method that you have to implement. Not sure what to look at here. I suggest posting a question with all the details that you have. Cheers!

Comment: the question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61135045/getapplication-in-firebasemessagingservice