# getApplication () in FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Apparently FirebaseInstanceIdService is depricated. So, I'm trying to changed this code:

```
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

public class InstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(@Nullable String token) {
        if (token != null) {
            ((SubApp) getApplication()).getRepository().registerInstanceId(token);
        }
    }
}
```

to the code below and adapt to the new Firebase requirements:

```
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;

public class InstanceIDService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onNewToken (@Nullable String token) {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(@Nullable String token) {
        if (token != null) {
            ((SubApp) InstanceIDService.this.getApplication()).getRepository().registerInstanceId(token);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems `getApplication()` does not work here. Even with `getActivity().getApplication()`. The error is:

> cannot resolve method `getApplication()`.

Also I have the error below for @override in FirebaseMessagingService:

> Method does not override method from superclass

Comment: the above code doesn't show any errors when I run.

Comment: Don't see any errors here. Even `getApplication()` should work as it should before. Try clean building your project. For the override error, you need to implement all of it's abstract methods, I think you're missing `onMessageReceived()`